# Can't find variable when adding data to Flatlist from json in React-Native

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm new to react native, so please be kind! I am trying to populate a Flatlist using a JSON.

Below is my JSON data

```
{
   "h1":{
      "baseprice":899,
      "description":"Upto Waist length Hair",
      "imageUrl":"https://i.imgur.com/0IgYzAv.jpg'",
      "price":799,
      "time":"25 min",
      "title":"Nourishing Hair Spa",
      "type":"Service"
   },
   "h2":{
      "baseprice":899,
      "description":"Touch Up of length less than 4 inches",
      "imageUrl":"https://i.imgur.com/q7ts4PZ.jpg",
      "price":799,
      "time":"45 min",
      "title":"INOA Root Touch Up",
      "type":"Service"
   }
}
```

Here is the code that I used to push the JSON data in to my Flatlist

```
export default class Office extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch("https://stylmate1.firebaseio.com/hair.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        });
        console.log(dataSource);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={(item) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

As soon as I refresh the App I get an error
**Can't find variable : dataSource**
But if I console.log(responseJson); then I get the complete JSON object.

I don't know what am I doing wrong here. Please help me in fixing this.

Comment: is the h1, h2 important to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FlatList is supposed to look like this:

```
return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item[1].title}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
```

You have to destructure the `item` in order to use it.

Output:

[image]

Working Example code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  const [dataSource, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://stylmate1.firebaseio.com/hair.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setData(responseJson);
        console.log(responseJson);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {dataSource ? (
        <FlatList
          data={Object.entries(dataSource)}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
              <Card>
                <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{item[1].title}</Text>
              </Card>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[Expo Snack Live Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/object_flatlist)

Comment: code is already updated to fetch it from url

Comment: Yes sir! Many Thanks, you are are Godsend.

Comment: Glad it helped, happy coding.

Comment: Hello Ketan, I just want to bring into your notice that now I getting "JSON Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" error. Can you kindly advise how to fix this. Check it here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162525/while-fetching-data-from-json-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted)

Answer (score 0):

The Error happens because you are trying to log dataSource which is wrong it should be this.state.dataSource.

```
console.log(dataSource);
```

change it to

```
console.log(this.state.dataSource);
```

in your .then() block

Comment: Thanks you sir. Also my flatlist isn't rendering. It's blank.

Comment: Problem is in destructuring in renderItem= {({item})=> your components}

Comment: May be that can help

Answer (score 0):

firstly,

`console.log(dataSource);`

should change to

`console.log(this.state.dataSource);`

However, you may not get the correct console.log since set state is async. You get better and accurate answer with responseJson

Secondly, flatList requires an array of objects structure, you need to convert them using the following methods. I moved your "h1", and "h2" into the object and label them as key.

```js
const original = {
   "h1":{
      "baseprice":899,
      "description":"Upto Waist length Hair",
      "imageUrl":"https://i.imgur.com/0IgYzAv.jpg'",
      "price":799,
      "time":"25 min",
      "title":"Nourishing Hair Spa",
      "type":"Service"
   },
   "h2":{
      "baseprice":899,
      "description":"Touch Up of length less than 4 inches",
      "imageUrl":"https://i.imgur.com/q7ts4PZ.jpg",
      "price":799,
      "time":"45 min",
      "title":"INOA Root Touch Up",
      "type":"Service"
   }
}

const newArray = Object.keys(original).map( key => ({...original[key], key }))

console.log(newArray)
```