# While fetching data from JSON Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: react-native, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to fetch data from json file in firebase. I get this error before the app loads sometimes. The App still works.

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Kindly help me to fix this.

Here is my code :

```
const [dataSource, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonurlcomeshere/banners.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setData(responseJson);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54954385/5669120

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-hooks. Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442582/react-hooks-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)